# Lodash: _filter Collection with another Collection

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash

quick question: I have two collections and I would like to filter Collection B only if the id of collection B is available in collection A and if its

Collection A:

```
{
  Hz6NkEhA7HeQbYv1D9cF1nJW9qg1: true,
  IpU5WL7NcCcPP54Y20awU0SgdGu2: true,
  L1TOEwgwtbMjVBWMvbrZDvQprO72: true,
  PzoRPT0YPxMP6xCBxioGk2bigzN2: false,
  Q45P0PgObWPsbm0TwrUjwUAd5rT2: false
}
```

Collection B:

```
{
  0: {
    id: 'Hz6NkEhA7HeQbYv1D9cF1nJW9qg1'
  },
  1: {
    id: 'Q45P0PgObWPsbm0TwrUjwUAd5rT2'
  },
  2: {
    id: 'Q45P0PgObWPsbm0TwrUjwUAd5rT2'
  }
}
```

How can I make use of lodash to filter those two arrays? 
I am stuck with those different objects, arrays etc...

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Is there a question in here somewhere? Because it looks like a work assignment.

Comment: Sorry Tomalak. I edited my answer and would like to make use of lodash to use _filter.

Comment: *"...those two arrays"*: they are not arrays (you could also help yourself and take care of more logical places to have line breaks and indent properly). To answer your question *"How can I make use of lodash to filter"*: by trying, by reading documentation, looking up similar questions and answers, trying again, ... If you get stuck *while* doing so, come back and ask a specific question about that.

Answer (score 0):

You're collections are not arrays (they're objects), so the lodash `_.pickBy` method is probably more suitable for this. For `_.pickBy`, you give the object to pick from as the first argument, then your filter function as the second argument. That filter function will be invoked with two arguments: the key and the value of the item from the collection.

So for what you want, you can either ensure that the id exists in the first collection and has a value of `true` (demonstrated in `colC`), or pick items where the id exists in the first collection *at all*, regardless of value (demonstrated in `colD`). Hopefully one of those two will be what you wanted.

```js
const colA = {
  Hz6NkEhA7HeQbYv1D9cF1nJW9qg1: true,
  IpU5WL7NcCcPP54Y20awU0SgdGu2: true,
  L1TOEwgwtbMjVBWMvbrZDvQprO72: true,
  PzoRPT0YPxMP6xCBxioGk2bigzN2: false,
  Q45P0PgObWPsbm0TwrUjwUAd5rT2: false,
  Hz6NkEhA7HeQbYv1D9cF1nJW9qg1: true,
}

const colB = {
  0: {
    id: 'Hz6NkEhA7HeQbYv1D9cF1nJW9qg1'
  },
  1: {
    id: 'Q45P0PgObWPsbm0TwrUjwUAd5rT2'
  },
  2: {
    id: 'Q45P0PgObWPsbm0TwrUjwUAd5rT2'
  }
}

const colC = _.pickBy(colB, val => colA[val.id])
console.log(colC)

const colD = _.pickBy(colB, val => val.id in colA);
console.log(colD)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.js"></script>
```